# Linux Sudo users disable change directory to /

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, rhel

We are using `sudo` users with limited commands to execute and assigned default home directory `/home/sudouser` but if that particular `sudo` user is running command `cd \` its changing the directory to the main root directory `/`. This behaviour is totally insecure for us.

We need it such that if the `sudo` user is entering `cd /` or `cd` it changes directory to their home directory `/home/sudouser`

Please let us know how we can implement this?

Comment: I would advice against denying a sudo user access to directory since the purpose of a Sudo user is to allow it to do whatever it wants, create Users with restrictive access instead. However if you still wish to go ahead this link can help you [Prevent User Access](https://superuser.com/questions/735172/how-to-prevent-sudo-users-from-running-specific-commands)

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score -2):

Don't ever try to restrict a sudo user to only a directory or a command, a sudo user can by definition do what he wants.

In your case, having a script that assigns the home directory is I think a better idea. To solve the trouble of permissions look for the suid bit in permissions: http://www.linuxnix.com/suid-set-suid-linuxunix/

For example: create a sh file that has the following permissions: "-rwsr--r--" that is owned by root and as a group that can be accessed by the user whom you want to use the script.

Then in the file you create a simple script to execute the command to change default directory with let's say two parameters (username and directory)